# Main Header (H1) Pulling from Page Title

Tags: wordpress

The H1 Header is pulling from the Page title. I want to be able to customize the header and not have it pull.

Can anyone assist?

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo(‘name’); }
elseif (is_category() ) { echo strip_tags(category_description()); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
elseif (is_page() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
else { wp_title(‘’,true); } ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? I'm not exactly following what you are saying. What do you mean by "pull"?

Comment: http://rocketspace.staging.wpengine.com/corporate-innovation-teams/

Comment: Visit that page.  The first header is the theme. The second is my custom header that I formatted. see how the first header pulls exactly the page title?  I don't want that and plus the header seems too big.